# DAX Advanced question with Time Intelligence and logic

Tags: switch-statement, dax, powerbi-desktop

this is my first post.

I am stuck with an advanced DAX problem. So far, I could  not find anything in forums or anywhere that has worked. Even seasoned professionals have only provided ideas that have not worked.

Client is a machine builder who sells expensive machines all over the world.

The usual reports and visuals are all working fine, margins, revenue, geo-revenue on a world map, filters for product categories, all going great.

It is only this next problem that I have been stuck with for 3 weeks now. I have tried Nested IFs, tried SWITCH, tried to use variables, but nothing has worked so far.

I have a FACT table called "Invoices_2019-2022" which of course includes net sales price, CustomerID, DateInitiaded (when the project was started) and DateInvoice (when the final invoice was issued), ProjectID.

Then there is a DIM table for the customers, connected through the CustomerID. ONE on the Customer side, MANY on the Invoices side.

The company wants quarterly reports, where they can select the quarter with a slicer with radio buttons. That is all working so far except the next point:

They want a table with a list of customers, where in the final column it says one of 4 categories:

NEW CUSTOMER - has bought a project this year for the first time, never before

LY CUSTOMER - has bought at least once last year but not since then

RETURNING CUSTOMER - has bought at least twice in the last 2 years, possibly also this year

OLD CUSTOMER - has bought at least once but not in the last 2 years

At first I thought, this would be simple. But 3 weeks later, I have no more ideas.

Anyone? Thanks a lot.

I have tried to create variables, for example

VAR YearSelected = SELECTEDVALUE(Date)

and then integrate that into a SWITCH function, but I kept getting errors that I did not understand.

I have tried Nested IFs, which gave me some partial solutions.

I have tried DATEDIFF, but my knowledge of that function is too shallow.

I asked a seasoned PBI consultant who gave me a formula that my PBI DAX editor would not even accept.

Asked ChatGPT for help, which produced either partial results or errors, added code all night long, with the same results.

[Screenshot of data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6TD7.png)

My last attempt at the code was this:

CustCat =

VAR CurrentYear = YEAR(MAX('invoices_2019-2022'[Date Initiated]))

VAR LastTwoYears = CALCULATETABLE('invoices_2019-2022', 'invoices_2019-2022'[Date Initiated] >= DATE(CurrentYear -2, 1, 1)
&& 'invoices_2019-2022'[Date Initiated] < DATE(CurrentYear, 1,1))

VAR CustomerPurchases = CALCULATETABLE(
VALUES('invoices_2019-2022'[CustomerID]),

'invoices_2019-2022'[CustomerID] IN VALUES(dim_customers[CustID])
)

VAR FirstPurchaseYear = MINX(CustomerPurchases,

YEAR(SUMMARIZE('invoices_2019-2022', 'invoices_2019-2022'[Date Initiated]))

)

RETURN

```
SWITCH(TRUE(),

COUNTROWS(CustomerPurchases) =0, "NEUKUNDE",

FirstPurchaseYear = CurrentYear && COUNTROWS(LastTwoYears) = 0, "NEUKUNDE",

COUNTROWS(LastTwoYears) > 0, "BESTANDSKUNDE",

COUNTROWS(LastTwoYears) = 0 && COUNTROWS(CustomerPurchases) > 0,
```

"ALTKUNDE",

```
BLANK()
```

)

Someone has asked about the definition of the year in the comments. This is my calendar DAX:

```
DateTable = ADDCOLUMNS(CALENDARAUTO(),
  
 "MonthNo", MONTH([Date]),   
 "MonthName", FORMAT([Date],"MMMM"),
 "Quarter", QUARTER([Date]),
 "Year", YEAR([Date]),
 "Day", DAY([Date]),
 "WeekdayNum", WEEKDAY([Date]),
 "WeekdayName",FORMAT([Date],"DDDD"),
 "YearMonth", FORMAT([Date], "YYYY-MM"),
 "YearQuarter", FORMAT([Date], "YYYY-Q"))
```

Comment: Update your question with some the DAX expressions you have tried. Define "Year" - calendar year or fiscal year (when does it start) or 12 months to todays' date.